# What is causing this 'narrowing conversion' warning?

Tags: data-type, compiler, constants

Because I'm still figuring out 'Arduino C' I leave all warnings on.

Recently I got this one:

`narrowing conversion of '(int)(((unsigned char)bx_0) | ((unsigned char)bx_1))' from 'int' to 'const byte...` etc.

...referring to this line:

```
const byte pinMask[3] = {bx_0, bx_1, bx_0 | bx_1};
```

...pointing to the `or` symbol.

The code in question (much simplified to recreate this):

```
const int latch[2] = {2, 4};

const byte bx_0 = 1 << latch[0];
const byte bx_1 = 1 << latch[1];

const byte pinMask[3] = {bx_0, bx_1, bx_0 | bx_1};
```

(This happens whether I use `byte`, `uint8_t`, or `unsigned char` everywhere.)

Without the `or` operator, no warning. If `bx_0` and `bx_1` are simple bytes, not shifted into existence, no warning. If I do this:

```
const byte pinMask[3] = {bx_0, bx_1, (byte)(bx_0 | bx_1)};
```

...again, no warning.

However, I get no complaints about this:

```
const byte notMask = !(bx_1 | bx_0);
```

...so a further condition is that the problem `or` has to be in an initializer list. Yikes.

I don't get it. There's no way an `or` of two bytes can force widening, so where did the `(int)` cast come from? It apparently has something to do with the `1 << latch[0]` code, but the result of that is still a byte, by definition.

I have a solution -- the `(byte)` cast -- but in the real code it's ugly and feels unnecessary. Everything is already just bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning message arises when a compiler complies with [C/C++ specifications](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard).

According to ISO/IEC 9899:2011 part 6.5.12.2 (“Bitwise inclusive OR operator”),

> Each of the operands shall have integer type

Thus, in the evaluation of `bx_0 | bx_1` within the statement `const byte pinMask[3] = {bx_0, bx_1, bx_0 | bx_1};`, the operands `bx_0` and `bx_1` are converted to `int` type before being OR'd together.  This produces an `int` result, which then must be narrowed to `byte` before it can be stored in the  `byte` array.

Knowing that the `(byte)` cast is necessary because of C/C++ specifications should convert your view of the cast from “ugly” and “unnecessary” to “necessary” and either “ok” or “oh well”.  :)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the issue, except that all the conditions are necessary for the warning: complex definition, bitwise operator, initializer list. Remove any one and it doesn't warn. And OK, I'll accept 'necessary' (-: but I'm keeping "ugly" because in the actual code there are 16 elements to `pinMask[]`, some with three `or`'s.